# Can anyone help with these markings?

Tags: translation, meaning, character-identification

[image]I have bought this bowl in an auction and I'm looking for help with these markings. I've used Google lens but it keeps coming up with allsorts.
Many thank

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 义谦堂（a brand)，龙年制(made in the dragon year (2026/2014/2002/..)

Comment: It is in traditional Characters, 義謙堂，龍年製, not simplified

Comment: Please don’t use Simplified Chinese when a text isn’t in Simplified Chinese for [character-identification] questions - it’s really confusing.

Comment: Is the brand Yiqiantang?? When searching traditional Chinese that is what it comes up with. I believe from your answer the bowl was made/painted in the 1980s.